# How can I chose one /META-INF/context.xml during the Maven's package generation?

Tags: java, maven

I have a huge application, running in different environments with different configurations.
So I need generate packages with different `/META-INF/context.xml`.

This is my `META-INF/` folder:

```
META-INF/
  context.xml  
  context2.xml  
  context3.xml  
  context4.xml
```

I've already tried the **maven-antrun-plugin**, but it can't handle files inside `META-INF/`.

Now, I'm trying the **maven-war-plugin**, but it doesn't rename or copy files. It only add or exclude files. So I need some help.

I want to generate a war package choosing only one of them, renaming or overwriting the original `context.xml`.

**Note:** I'm using profiles.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use the `<packagingExcludes>` and `<packagingIncludes>` in the `maven-war-plugin`.

For example to exclude `context.xml`, and `context1.xml`:

```xml
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml,META-INF/context1.xml</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can use regex in the include and exclude section to filter out a wide range of files. This maven [wiki](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) covers more examples and details on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't put the input files in META-INF. Put them in a folder that maven is not aware of. Now set a property to a file name in each profile

```
  <properties>
    <folder>path/to/context/files</folder>
  </properties>

<profile>
  <id>foo</id>
  <properties>
    <filename>context2.xml</filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Now use the antrun plugin and define an ant property:

```
<property name="maven.context.file" value="${folder}/${filename}"/>
```

Before you call your ant target, [as mentioned on the antrun usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html).